# How can I change accordion style?

Tags: theming, navigation

I added the Accordion module on Drupal 7 and it works without any problem, but I would like to change the style of the view. I have already read the documentation, but I don't know how I can put CSS styles to the view.

I can add styles to the views-accordion.css file but I don't know how to add the classes to the view or how to make it use my styles instead of its default styles.

**Update :**

I edited the file views-view-accordion.tpl.php, but still no result ! The styles will not change !

Answer (score 1):

You have to check this:

This module comes with a default css stylesheet, which **you can disable in the options**.

Files included for your convinence:

- views-acordion.css - A default stylesheet with how the classes the
  author thought would be best used.
- views-view-accordion.tpl.php - **copy/paste into your theme
  directory** - please the comments in this file for
  requirements/instructions. Both files are commented to explain how
  things work. Do read them to speed things up.

So you have to follow this instructions, add a custom styles on your theme, add custom classes in your template (If you need it), but dont forget default clasess make animation work.

Comment: Thank you for copying and pasting what is in the module page :S I already saw it in read me file too ! Well it's not working ! My question is if there is any solution to make it work !

Comment: You are wellcome, I sugest you to do constructive comments, for me it works, so give more details to help you: module version, some debugging things you have done, etc.

Comment: Actually I think I found the solution :) but I have to check it tomorrow.